# Can I access a child objects variable from a parent?

Tags: c#, class, variables, inheritance, polymorphism

So let's say I have a class called "Animal" which is inherited by "Cat".
If I now have an array of animals can I somehow access cat variables from it (if the animal is also a cat of course)?

Comment: you can cast animal to a cat. there are multiple ways to do it. `((Cat)MyAnimal).Purr()` or `(MyAnimal as Cat).Purr()` or better `if (MyAnimal is Cat myCat) myCat.Purr()`

Comment: Consider while every `Cat` is an `Animal`, not every `Animal` is a `Cat`, so that conversion may fail. Anyway: there are hundreds of similar questions, just **search and try something**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) operator,

> The is operator checks if the result of an expression is compatible
> with a given type, or (starting with C# 7.0) tests an expression
> against a pattern.

```
foreach(var animal in animals)
{
   if(animal is Cat lovelyCat)
   {
      //You can use lovelyCat as object of Cat
   }
}
```

Note: `is` operator supports [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern) from C# version 7.0

Comment: Or you could just use `Object.GetType()` which is available to all classes. Then you don't have to depend on a new version of `C#`

Comment: @RyanWilson pattern matching is not about **checking** if a variable is of a given type. `animal is Cat` works from C#1. It´s just a convenient way to perform the cast and return the result, as if you would perform an as-cast and check for null.

Comment: yeah As HimBromBeere said, `animal is Cat` is not pattern matching.Conversion of animal to lovelyCat is supported in C# 7. If you are working with lower version of C#, the you need split condition statement into two lines like, `if(animal is Cat){ var lovelyCat = (Cat)animal ; ..}`

Comment: @HimBromBeere `Object.GetType()` is still going to be just as valid, you need to check if the `Animal` is a `Cat` before casting.

Comment: @RyanWilson sure, but doing this using `GetType` won´t cover all cases, e.g. not if something inherits `Cat`. Of course that´s out of scope of the question, but I´t rather go with `animal is Cat` instead of `animal.GetType() == typeof(Cat)`.